# SIGABRT error in Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 Tutorial

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying work phonegap facebook connect plugin facebook SDK 3.1 but its doesnt work!

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x973dca60:  movl   $524616, %eax
0x973dca65:  calll  0x973de4c2                ; _sysenter_trap
0x973dca6a:  jae    0x973dca7a                ; __pthread_kill + 26
0x973dca6c:  calll  0x973dca71                ; __pthread_kill + 17
0x973dca71:  popl   %edx
0x973dca72:  movl   26027(%edx), %edx
0x973dca78:  jmpl   *%edx
0x973dca7a:  ret    
0x973dca7b:  nop
```

Application Logs:

```
2012-11-07 16:59:19.649 facebookTEST[13324:c07] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-11-07 16:59:19.791 facebookTEST[13324:c07] [LOG] Cordova Facebook Connect plugin initialized successfully.
2012-11-07 16:59:19.797 facebookTEST[13324:c07] [LOG] Got the user's session: 
2012-11-07 16:59:19.999 facebookTEST[13324:c07] -[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa42c670
2012-11-07 16:59:19.999 facebookTEST[13324:c07] Failure before/during install ping: -[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa42c670
2012-11-07 16:59:34.707 facebookTEST[13324:c07] -[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa142500
2012-11-07 16:59:34.707 facebookTEST[13324:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa142500'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e5012 0x2805e7e 0x2704bd 0x1d4bbc 0x1d494e 0x160090 0x1d5a1d 0x907b3 0x73cbd 0x73a51 0x83a9f 0x844a5 0x2cad53f 0x2cbf014 0x2caf7d5 0x18baf5 0x18af44 0x18ae1b 0x36367e3 0x3636668 0x42065c 0x2626 0x2555)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Doesnt have any idea ?

Comment: Could you provide more details about the app you're running? Are you running a sample app?

Comment: Yes, but sample app dont working :/ (Same code)

Comment: My sample code is here http://enes.me/facebookTest.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Your current setting]

You've incorrectly added the Facebook settings. The correct way is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's working, thank you ! by the way

The scheme code is;

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>[YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID]</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb[YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID]</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```